# Como fazer uma consulta SQL que retorne um objeto em vez de uma array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Não tem muito o que falar. O que eu preciso é saber como fazer uma consulta que me retorne um objeto em vez de um array no formato:

```
$eventos = [
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-01-26'), 'Titulo #1'),
    new Evento(2, new \DateTime('2015-01-31'), 'Titulo #2'),
    new Evento(3, new \DateTime('2015-03-02'), 'Titulo #3'),
    new Evento(4, new \DateTime('2015-05-04'), 'Titulo #4'),
    new Evento(5, new \DateTime('2015-05-08'), 'Titulo #5'),
    new Evento(6, new \DateTime('2015-08-01'), 'Titulo #6'),
    new Evento(7, new \DateTime('2015-09-14'), 'Titulo #7'),
    new Evento(8, new \DateTime('2015-09-19'), 'Titulo #8'),
    new Evento(9, new \DateTime('2015-11-10'), 'Titulo #9')
];
```

Comment: Qual é a API para conexão com o banco de dados?

Comment: vc já viu este [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php), com o `fetch_fields` retorna o objeto...

Comment: Eu vou usar PDO @rray

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` no `fetch()` ou `fetchAll()` resolve? da pra fazer de outro jeito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o PDO pode transformar cada linha retornada do banco usando a constante `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, será criado um objeto da stdClass, suas propriedades teram o mesmo nome das colunas do banco de dados.

```
$stmt = $db->prepre($sql);
$itens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Caso sua classe tenha comportamentos especificos é melhor cria os objetos manualmente em um laço.

```
$stmt = $db->prepre($sql);
$itens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$eventos = array();
foreach($itens as $item){
   $e = new Evento($item->id, $item->data, $item->titulo);
   $eventos[] = $e;
   echo $e->eventoFoiAdiado();
}
```

Comment: Como eu printo @rray o objeto retornado dessa consulta e o que é **echo $e->eventoFoiAdiado();**?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius, so com `FETCH_OBJ`, faça um foreach, e chame assim `$item->nome_campo_DB`. `eventoFoiAdiado()` é caso sua classe tenha outros métodos que precise executar.

Answer (score 2):

Usando PDO faça:

```
$result = $con->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Para exibir os resultados `print $result->name;`